# How to add a watermark to an editbox in an outlook 2013 add-in

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, watermark, editbox

I've created an add-in for Outllook (in C#) in which I have an EditBox. I need the EditBox to default to "user prompt" but when the user clicks in the EditBox the "user prompt" to disappear.

I know there's a TextChanged event but can't work out how to set HasFocus and LostFocus events, if this is the approach I should take?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that EditBox is within a RibbonGroup in a custom tab.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible. The `RibbonEditBox` only supports the `TextChanged` event, nothing more. There is no other event to hook on, nor a property that enables you to set a watermark.

Also, [Office Ribbon XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd925058(v=office.12).aspx) does not support additional events.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I couldn't see a way either...Is there an alternative to the RibbonEditBox for entering text that has an OnClick or Got/LostFocus event?

Comment: That's pretty rubbish, I would expect behavior like this to come out of the box...In the Home tab -> Find group there's what appears to be a TextBox for looking up contacts with the default watermark "Search People", this would do, any idea what sort of control that is?

Comment: Yes, that is built into Office itself. The controls provided to us are really basic.